# Vuforia Cordova Plugin randomly dissappearing from PhoneGap Application

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, vuforia

In current project I have to implement Vuforia support in PhoneGap mobile application, dedicated for Android Platform.

I'm using the following Cordova plugin - https://github.com/mattrayner/cordova-plugin-vuforia

As far as I studied, PhoneGap utilizes Cordova platform, so there is compability in using Cordova plugins in PhoneGap apllications as well.

My issue is that Vuforia plugin randomly "dissappears" from application - both build to *.apk file and opened on mobile device via command 'phonegap serve'. It happens as well using example application mentioned in owner's repository: https://github.com/dsgriffin/cordova-vuforia-example

The way I'm investing the issue is to explore the content of 'navigator' object, from which the Vuforia Plugin is called, by logging it to console. However, the plugin is randomly present or absent and plugin api is not working as well (again, even on example application posted above).

Did anyone expierience similar issue with Vuforia Plugin for Cordova, or could recommend alternative to implement Vuforia in PhoneGap app?

Tested on: Mac OS, Windows 10 using PhoneGap desktop App and Mint Cinnamon 18.3 and Android 6.0 device

Answer (score 0):

All I can recommend you on this case is to switch to a more professional IDE that is specifically prepared for Cordova apps, like [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/features/mobile-app-development/). You can use the Community edition, which is free. It comes with [some drawbacks](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/), but it can manage, install and uninstall plugins in a very convenient way. In case there are errors installing the plugin, submit your comment here and I'll update the answer accordingly.